# Disconnect other users from DHCP client list

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, dsl-modem

When I log in to my modem webpage I can see lot of employees are connected to WiFi network. This is okay.

I have full access to the system and i want to disconnect the particular employee from the WIFI  if he is downloading or using excessive amount of data. Currently i can see the IP address, MAC address, etc. of the connected users.

Is there any tools available or is there any other way that I can accomplish the task ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if your modem has a kick-off capability. (Probably not)

Just removing the IP from the DHCP list does nothing because the IP is already issued.

I think your best bet would be to block that IP in the NAT settings so it has no more internet access. Because even if you could invalidate his IP address his computer would just ask for another. Blocking it from internet will keep that from happening. He will still have local LAN access (to servers on your network) but he can't access the internet.

If your modem had QOS-capabilities maybe it's even better you limit his download-speed to a crawl. That way he can still access internet but downloading large files will just be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *actively* kick users off of the network, either your modem/router must support this (unlikely) or you must do it through their PC.

There are many ways to run remote commands on a PC. My preferred would be [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), which allows you to run remote commands on the machine as long as you have the username and password for an administrative account.

You could use PsExec to run the `ipconfig /release command` and they would release their assigned IP and disconnect.

To prevent them from getting another IP, however, you would need to block their MAC address in the modem/router.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some functionality in your networking device that will allow you to do that but it's unlikely. It sounds like you're referring to a wireless gateway devices issued by an ISP and those devices are severely lacking in functionality.

An alternative solution if you're concerned about bandwidth is to pick up a router that supports bandwidth control or IP QoS. This common feature allows you to limit bandwidth to specific endpoints based on MAC addresses. That will allow you to control how much bandwidth a computer/device can use.